# Comments behaviour between SO and Meta-SO seem odd?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

It takes 50 rep points to post a comment on SO and only 1 point on Meta which is confusing, why the difference in the first place. (This part has been answered.)

I cannot flag a comment as " this is a great comment " on Meta. Does this mean that I will be able to when I achieve 50 rep points like on SO? If so shouldn't that be spelled out in the FAQ.

Comment: when I say "upvote" a comment I mean flag a comment as "this is a great comment"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because meta is built for discussions. So being able to give a comment is much more important than on Stack Overflow, where giving answers is the most important thing.

Comment: Thats fine, but when can you flag a comment as  "this is a great comment", after 50 rep points?

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is by design. As meta is there for the sake of discussion in the first place, comments are a fundamental piece of privilege you should have.

Votes are another thing, though. While it *might* make sense for meta to have 1 rep user votes, I think they deliberately chose to disable it as you could create a thousand accounts and vote yourself with it.

Comment: What I mean though is that you can specifically upvote ( flag ) a comment as in "this is a great comment" which as far as I can tell doesn't get you anything.

Comment: It does get you a badge if you have 10 comments with +10 each.